# Uncaught TypeError: data[index] is undefined | Set input value in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote the below code which displays each item with {t.title}

When I click on each checkbox item, `plant_id: t.plant_id` is correctly stored in `setPlantsFill`

But when I try to enter input value, for example, the third value of `data[index]["effectiveness"] = e.target.value;`, an error is shown to me: `Uncaught TypeError: data[index] is undefined`
But if I enter in order, there is no problem

How can I solve this problem?

I want the final output for each item to be as (for example we have 3 item in allPlants):
`{ "plant_id": 2, "effectiveness": 100 }, { "plant_id": 24, "effectiveness": 80 }, { "plant_id": 13, "effectiveness": 15 }`

this is my code:

```
const [allPlants, setAllPlants] = useState([]);

const [plantsFill, setPlantsFill] = useState([]);

{allPlants.map((t, index) => {
              return (
                <div className="form-row mb-2" key={index}>
                  <div className="col-md-2">
                    <div className="form-check">
                      <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        className="form-check-input"
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          if (e.target.checked) {
                            setPlantsFill([
                              ...plantsFill,
                              {
                                plant_id: t.plant_id,
                              },
                            ]);
                          } else {
                            // remove from list
                            setPlantsFill(
                              plantsFill.filter(
                                (pItem) => pItem.plant_id !== t.plant_id
                              )
                            );
                          }
                        }}
                        value={plantsFill}
                      />

                      <label className="form-check-label">{t.title}</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div className="col-md-1">
              
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      className="form-control"
                      onChange={(e) => {
                        let data = [...plantsFill];
                        data[index]["effectiveness"] = e.target.value;
                        setPlantsFill(data);
                      }}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
```

Comment: Why not extract these long inline event handler into seperate methods? :)

Comment: @Raukaute For this one case, I will test first, if the output is correct, I will separate it

Comment: If you don't check the checkbox first, it means that your `plantsFill` is empty so you can't access it with `data[index]["effectiveness"]`, it is undefined.
And it is better to access  it with `plant_id`.

Comment: Don't you want to show the input of type text only if it is checked first ?

Comment: @OneQ My problem is in INPUT TEXT, for example, when I enter a value on the third item for the first time, this problem occurs.

Comment: As I said it is because your array `plantsFill` is empty and you use the index instead of the id

Comment: @OneQ When I insert value the first item and then insert value the 4th item, the problem is the same - There is no problem with being empty

Comment: Explain exactly the path you do. You click on the first checkbox and the 4th checkbox?

Comment: Also, you wrote `product_id` in `allPlants` but everywhere in your code it uses `plant_id`

Comment: @OneQ checkbox is ok , my problem is input text : `<input
                      type="text"
                      className="form-control"
                      onChange={(e) => {
                        let data = [...plantsFill];
                        data[index]["effectiveness"] = e.target.value;
                        setPlantsFill(data);
                      }}
                    />`

Comment: Please explain the path you do when it shows the error

Comment: @OneQ 

I really can't explain more than this :( - 

Please read my question again

Comment: SO, you have an error because when you try to enter your text at the second input for exemple (`data[1]`), this data is undefined. Because you use the index.
You should use the `plant_id` to find the correct index. And with your code you're obliged to check the checkbox to enter a value, otherwise it will throw an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the discussion I tried something and it works as I understand the problem :

```
const onCheckChange = (e, t) => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      setPlantsFill([
        ...plantsFill,
        {
          plant_id: t.plant_id
        }
      ]);
    } else {
      // remove from list
      setPlantsFill(
        plantsFill.filter((pItem) => pItem.plant_id !== t.plant_id)
      );
    }
  };

  const onTextChange = (e, t) => {
    let data = [...plantsFill];
    const index = data.findIndex((d) => d.plant_id === t.plant_id);
    if (index > -1) {
      data[index].effectiveness = e.target.value;
    }
    setPlantsFill(data);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {allPlants.map((t, index) => {
        return (
          <div className="form-row mb-2" key={index}>
            <div className="col-md-2">
              <div className="form-check">
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  className="form-check-input"
                  onChange={(e) => onCheckChange(e, t)}
                  value={!!plantsFill.find((p) => p.plant_id === t.plant_id)}
                />

                <label className="form-check-label">{t.title}</label>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="col-md-1">
              {!!plantsFill.find((p) => p.plant_id === t.plant_id) && (
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  onChange={(e) => onTextChange(e, t)}
                />
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: thanks a lot
im junior, for exercise to solve problem like this . i should work with algorithms?